# fixed table with header visible

Tags: html, css

I have two tables, the structure of which is below. The first table is for the header, and the second is for the data. I get vertical scroll and that is fine. When I scroll, I need the header to be visible along with the data (header :fixed). This is working fine in Firefox 3.6 version, but in Firefox 11, 12, and 13 it is hiding the header. Below is the code. Please let me know:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" width="90%" bgcolor="#538ED5" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: fixed">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2" align="center" bgcolor="#FFCC99" style="font-size:'.$textsize.';"><b>Dates</b></th>
    <th colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFF99" style="font-size:'.$textsize.';"><b>EACM</b></th>
    <th colspan="3" align="center" bgcolor="#CCFF99" style="font-size:'.$textsize.';"><b>LOIS</b></th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>data1</td>
    <td>data2</td>
    <td>data3</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to a page with all of your code on it?

Comment: maybe you should try `position: fixed`, instead of `overflow`?